# How to apply two templates and group the result by size and used template with xslt

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, nokogiri

I am trying to parse an XML and produce an HTML which could be used for printing.

The content of the elements in the XML are presented like cards and have information for the frontside as well as the backside. Eight cards would fit on a page.
To make life easier in the HTML/CSS world for positioning I would like to pre-arrange the XSLT output as follows:
For 16 elements in the input I would like to have first the frontside output of the first 8 elements, then the backside output of the first 8 elements in a different order that they match the corresponding frontside when two-sided printing is used, then the frontside output of the next 8 elements, etc.

The ordering for the backside is like this: first half in reverse order then the second half in reverse order. Ex. Backside card 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5.

Or for the following input(for the sake of simplicity I just use 4 cards per page for the example):

```
<cards>
  <card>
    <question>First for the front</question>
    <answer>First to the back</answer>
  </card>
  <card>
    <question>Second for the front</question>
    <answer>Second to the back</answer>
  </card>
  <card>
    <question>Third for the front</question>
    <answer>Third to the back</answer>
  </card>
  <card>
    <question>Fourth for the front</question>
    <answer>Fourth to the back</answer>
  </card>
  <card>
    <question>Fifth for the front</question>
    <answer>Fifth to the back</answer>
  </card>
</cards>
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
<html><body>
   <div>
     <div class="card1 front">First for the front</div>
     <div class="card2 front">Second for the front</div>
     <div class="card3 front">Third for the front</div>
     <div class="card4 front">Fourth for the front</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="card2 back">Second to the back</div>
     <div class="card1 back">First to the back</div>
     <div class="card4 back">Fourth to the back</div>
     <div class="card3 back">Third to the back</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="card1 front">Fifth for the front</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="card1 back">Fifth to the back</div>
   </div>
 </body></html>
```

I have an idea to process the elements twice over next-match and modes but I have no idea how to combine it with the sorting/grouping I would like to apply.

I would be really thankful for a pointer into the right direction.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: "*first the frontside output of the first 8 elements, then the backside output of the first 8 elements in reverse order,*" I don't see that in your example output. Why is the order 2, 1, 4, 3?

Comment: I use ruby and the nokogiri library for the xslt processing. So only xslt 1.0 or if you know another good xslt 2.0 library for ruby I could use it.

Comment: It can be done with XSLT 1.0 too. But you need to clarify the logic behind the ordering of the back sides.

Comment: There is no XSLT 2.0 library for Ruby, as far as I know - and Nokogiri is the best option. I've retagged the question for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is not just the reverse ordering (I clarified it in the description). Because the back side cards should match the front side cards with two-sided printing it is a little bit a special ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make this generic - we want `$rows` rows of `$cols` cards each per page, and on the answer side each *row* needs to be printed in reverse order.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="rows" select="2" />
  <xsl:param name="cols" select="2" />
  <xsl:variable name="pageSize" select="$rows * $cols" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cards/card[position() mod $pageSize = 1]" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="card">
    <!-- fronts -->
    <div>
      <xsl:call-template name="printRows">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="order" select="'ascending'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
    <!-- backs -->
    <div>
      <xsl:call-template name="printRows">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="order" select="'descending'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="printRows">
    <xsl:param name="element" />
    <xsl:param name="order" />
    <xsl:variable name="thePage"
        select=". | following-sibling::card[position() &lt; $pageSize]" />
    <!-- split into rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$thePage[position() mod $cols = 1]">
      <xsl:variable name="theRow"
          select=". | following-sibling::card[position() &lt; $cols]" />
      <!-- and process each row in appropriate order -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$theRow/*[$element]">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" order="{$order}" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="question">
    <div class="card{(count(../preceding-sibling::card) mod $pageSize) + 1} front">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="answer">
    <div class="card{(count(../preceding-sibling::card) mod $pageSize) + 1} back">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will work for any grid size, just set (or pass in) the number of rows and columns via the top two parameters.  To calculate the class names I count preceding siblings so the numbers are based on the full set of `card` elements in their original document order - the `position()` function would give the *sorted* position, and only within the current row.

However, I think there may be a flaw in your logic for the output - in the final (short) row, the back of card five should be in the *second* column rather than the first, in order to print opposite its respective front.  In general, if a "back" row has fewer than `$cols` cards in it then you need to left-pad it with empty divs to get everything to line up.  One way to do that would be to modify the `printRows` template like this:

```
<!-- split into rows -->
<xsl:for-each select="$thePage[position() mod $cols = 1]">
  <xsl:variable name="theRow"
      select=". | following-sibling::card[position() &lt; $cols]" />

  <xsl:if test="$order = 'descending'">
    <!--
    special case for a short reverse row (i.e. the last row of the last page) - we need
    to left-pad this row with empty columns to get the right positioning
    -->
    <xsl:call-template name="emptyDivs">
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$cols - count($theRow)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>

  <!-- and process each row in appropriate order -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$theRow/*[$element]">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="{$order}" data-type="number" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Where the `emptyDivs` template is

```
<xsl:template name="emptyDivs">
  <xsl:param name="num"/>
  <xsl:if test="$num &gt; 0">
    <div class="padding back" />
    <xsl:call-template name="emptyDivs">
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will produce the following output for a two row by two column page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="card1 front">First for the front</div>
      <div class="card2 front">Second for the front</div>
      <div class="card3 front">Third for the front</div>
      <div class="card4 front">Fourth for the front</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="card2 back">Second to the back</div>
      <div class="card1 back">First to the back</div>
      <div class="card4 back">Fourth to the back</div>
      <div class="card3 back">Third to the back</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="card1 front">Fifth for the front</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="padding back"></div>
      <div class="card1 back">Fifth to the back</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

or the following for two rows by three columns:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="card1 front">First for the front</div>
      <div class="card2 front">Second for the front</div>
      <div class="card3 front">Third for the front</div>
      <div class="card4 front">Fourth for the front</div>
      <div class="card5 front">Fifth for the front</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="card3 back">Third to the back</div>
      <div class="card2 back">Second to the back</div>
      <div class="card1 back">First to the back</div>
      <div class="padding back"></div>
      <div class="card5 back">Fifth to the back</div>
      <div class="card4 back">Fourth to the back</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 transformation achieves the required structure:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/cards">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="card[position() mod 4 = 1]">
          <xsl:variable name="thisPage" select="
            . | following-sibling::card[position() &lt; 4]
          " />
          <div class="front">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisPage/question" />
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisPage/answer">
              <xsl:sort select="substring('2143', position(), 1)" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="card/*">
    <div class="card">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I take it that you don't *really* need the numbered CSS class names. Adding them makes things unnecessarily complicated.

If necessary you can achieve the same thing easily in your CSS stylesheet using `nth-child`.

```css
.back .card:nth-child(1) {
    /* this is card2 */
}
```

That being said, you could also have achieved the *entire* positioning on the back side independent of source order by combining `position: absolute` and `nth-child` in CSS. This way special ordering in XSLT would have been unnecessary.